# How do I wrap all files from a Bazel filegroup into a directory?

Tags: bazel

How can I wrap all files of a `filegroup` in a directory and create a new target out of that?

My use case is that I have a filegroup inside test-data/BUILD.bazel but the test runner expects the files inside a directory called `test-data`.

```
filegroup(
    name = "render-test-files",
    srcs = glob([
        "integration/**",
        "tests/**",
        "linux-gcc8-release/**",
        "expectations/platform-all/**",
        "ignores/**",
    ], allow_empty = False)
    visibility = [
        "//render-test:__subpackages__",
    ],
)
```

I cannot use a `genrule` because it requires all output files to be listed explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To collect files into a directory and have that considered a build artifact, you can write a custom rule returning `TreeArtifact` using [`declare_directory`](https://bazel.build/rules/lib/builtins/actions#declare_directory) action. In a very naive/trivial form (not portable, not checking if sources contain any files, ...) something like:

```
def _impl(ctx):
    outdir = ctx.actions.declare_directory("{}.dir".format(ctx.attr.name))
    args = ctx.actions.args()
    args.add(outdir.path)
    args.add_all(ctx.files.srcs)
    ctx.actions.run_shell(
        outputs = [outdir],
        inputs = ctx.files.srcs,
        arguments = [args],
        command = """
outdir="$1";
shift;
cp "$@" "${outdir}"
                """,
    )
    return [
        DefaultInfo(files = depset([outdir])),
    ]

dirrule = rule(
    _impl,
    attrs = {
        "srcs": attr.label_list(
            allow_files = True,
            mandatory = True,
        ),
    },
)
```

Which could then be used in a `BUILD` file with `mydir` now being directory containing copies of `file0[12]`:

```
load(":dirrule.bzl", "dirrule")

dirrule(
    name = "mydir",
    srcs = [
        "//myfiles:file01",
        "//myfiles:file02",
    ],
)
```

I would personally rather try to adapt the receiving tool to actually handle list of inputs... or if impossible (beyond my control), probably rather wrap its use (call) from (I presume already the case anyways) custom rule which would take that list and populate the tree (preferably symlink even if the tool isn't way broken) in shape it expects.

Comment: I think this may run into the max length of a shell command. But yes it looks like changing the test runner is the best course of action.

Comment: @BartLouwers If the command line gets too long, param file(s) may also be an option.